# Connect YAMNET audio classification to tflite_audio or tflite

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Trying to connect tflite_audio package with a model named yamnet for audio classification .

Any idea whats wrong ? It worked with other tflite models so im guessing is something in bufferSize or sampleRate?

Can somehow connect it with the official support package tflite from pub dev? Seems more supported.

Anyone has done it before?

Thanks

Here is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tflite_audio/tflite_audio.dart';

class Mic2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Mic2({super.key});

  @override
  State<Mic2> createState() => Mic2State();
}

class Mic2State extends State<Mic2> {
  String _sound = "Press the button to start";
  bool _recording = false;
  Stream<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>? result;

  @override
  void initState() {
    TfliteAudio.loadModel(
        model: "Assets/1.tflite",
        label: "Assets/1.txt",
        inputType: 'decodedWav',
        numThreads: 1,
        isAsset: true);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _recorder() {
    String recognition = "";
    if (!_recording) {
      setState(() {
        _recording = true;
      });
      result = TfliteAudio.startAudioRecognition(
        sampleRate: 16000,
        bufferSize: 15600,
        numOfInferences: 5,
        detectionThreshold: 0.3,
      );
      result?.listen((event) {
        recognition = event["recognitionResult"];
      }).onDone(() {
        setState(() {
          _recording = false;
          _sound = recognition.split(" ")[1];
        });
      });
    }
  }

  void _stop() {
    TfliteAudio.stopAudioRecognition();
    setState(() => _recording = false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              const Text(
                "What's this sound?",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 60,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                ),
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: _recorder,
                color: _recording ? Colors.grey : Colors.pink,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                shape: const CircleBorder(),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                child: const Icon(Icons.mic, size: 60),
              ),
              Text(
                _sound,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My errors :

```
/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855): Failed to open event stream
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at flutter.tflite_audio.TfliteAudioPlugin.determineAudio(TfliteAudioPlugin.java:296)   
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at flutter.tflite_audio.TfliteAudioPlugin.onListen(TfliteAudioPlugin.java:244)
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel$IncomingStreamRequestHandler.onListen(EventChannel.java:218)
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel$IncomingStreamRequestHandler.onMessage(EventChannel.java:197)
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)   
E/EventChannel#AudioRecognitionStream(22855):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SERVICES LIBRARY ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following PlatformException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel
AudioRecognitionStream:
PlatformException(error, length=1; index=1, null, null)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:651:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:322:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:664:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
```